# Oracle - Change Table Position

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

i have an issue with oracle .
i was creating a table and then i about to add some changes that need to be done , when i add a new column on my table , the column get to most bottom right away , is it possible for me to move the column to a specific position?

[My Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ1D2.png)

is it possible to swap the position of REGIS_ID and REGIS_ID_SALES ?

Comment: No, I don't think you can do this, but then again it doesn't really matter, at least from the point of view of having any noticeable effect when querying the table.

Comment: It's not possible and also not required as you can give names of columns in order as required in the select clause or you can create a view with names of columns as required and use the view instead of the table.